# Evaluate date at "at" command scheduled time

Tags: linux, bash, at

I use a script file to run some tasks using the AT command, but in the log file the date echoed is the date when I set up AT command not the execution date.

What can I do to display the actual time of end of execution?

This is my script file content:

```
logFILE="/tmp/loggfile.log"

if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then echo "Please specify the run time, HH:MM "; exit 1; fi
runTIME=$1

at $runTIME <<< "
echo 'Running a task....'
echo 'An other task....'
echo 'END : (`date '+%H:%M'`)' >>$logFILE
"
echo "The command was scheduled to run at $runTIME"
```

If I run it at **16:00** with `./script.sh 23:20`, the task will be executed at **23:20** but in the log file I get `END : (16:00)`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date` is executed when the script runs because `` `…` `` syntax is inside double quotes. It's also inside inner single quotes but the most outer quotes count. The result is `at` doesn't "see" `` `date …` `` but its output.

Make outer quotes single, inner quotes double. `at` will get the entire string as is. When the time is right it will run `sh` which will see `` `date …` `` in double quotes and only then `date` will be evaluated:

```
at "$runTIME" <<< '
echo "Running a task...."
echo "An other task...."
echo "END : (`date +%H:%M`)" >>"$logFILE"
'
```

Note I dropped the most inner single quotes (`'+%H:%M'`). In my version they would vanish while passing the string to `at`; the code works without them anyway.